Linked Lists: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'
class ListNode:
      def __init__(self, val=0, next=None) -> None:
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

def list_link(nums):
    dummy = ListNode()  

    curr = dummy

    for i in nums:
        curr.next = ListNode(i) #line6
        curr = curr.next

I am new to DSA. In this code snippet to convert a list to a Linked List why do i get the following error if I change the code to this at line 6
class ListNode:
      def __init__(self, val=0, next=None) -> None:
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

def list_link(nums):
    dummy = ListNode() 

    curr = dummy

    for i in nums:
        curr.next = i  #line6
        curr = curr.next

The error i get is: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'
I would like to know the reasoning behind this error.
Why can't I assign the integer value directly to "curr".
Is'nt "curr" already a node in a linked list with val and next attributes?

Because i is not a ListNode object. Python Linkledlist addNode() not correct

The value of next should not be a number. It should be another list node object (and in this case presumably that list node object has your number as its value). It is the difference between a number and a list node object with a value property set to a number.

@VarunVishwa Read this. Already explained.

Assuming nums is a list of ints: i is an integer, so curr.next = i makes curr.next an integer, and curr = curr.next is an error since ints have no next attribute.

@001Okay thanks I get it now.
Will this work too? So if I do ' curr.next.val = i ' it should assign the node's value to i?

Use the ListNode constructor: def list_link(nums): cur = None; for i in nums: cur = ListNode(i, cur)

Curr.next = i 

Means you are trying to push an integer value as a node. It's like an address which should point toward a house is pointing toward a person.

So if I do ' curr.next.val = i ' it should assign the node's value to i?
